# Android: Google Maps app gives black screen after single tap, no error

Tags: android, google-maps, debugging, mobile, crash

Currently I just made an app with the API key to setup a Google Maps application.

It launches without an error, but I can't figure out why it gives a black screen after tapping the screen once. If I tap it twice it zooms in.
Even if it gives a black screen, it doesn't crash, since I am still able to open the onOptionsItemSelected menu.

When its black, I cant return back to the main map

Please proceed

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    GoogleMap m_googleMap;
    StreetViewPanorama m_StreetView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createMapView();
        createStreetView();

        m_googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

                if (m_StreetView != null) {

                    /**
                     * Hide the map view to expose the street view.
                     */
                    Fragment mapView = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(mapView).commit();

                    m_StreetView.setPosition(latLng);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void createStreetView() {
        m_StreetView = ((StreetViewPanoramaFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.streetView))
                .getStreetViewPanorama();
    }

    private void createMapView(){
        try {
            if(null == m_googleMap){
                m_googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.mapView)).getMap();

                if(null == m_googleMap) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error creating map",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException exception){
            Log.e("mapApp", exception.toString());
        }
    }

    private void addMarker(){
        if(null != m_googleMap){
            m_googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                                .title("Marker")
                                .draggable(true)
            );
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Edit 1
Added activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/streetView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanoramaFragment"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Can you show your layout xml that has `mapView` and `streetView`?

Comment: I'd like to notify you I added my activity_main.xml

Comment: I notice that you apply a `street view` for your app, and when you click the Map, you will go to street view. But the problem is: there are no street view for `LatLng` you set, so it will return the black screen. You can try to use the  `Latlng` of `-33.87365, 151.20689`. Notice that the `Latlng` need to be very specific.

Comment: I don't see how you show the map when you finish navigating the streetview though. How do you enable the mapview afterwards?